# Accepted, but not officially accepted

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen other questions that suggest solutions, but nothing open-ended or absolute. What are we supposed to do, if anything, when a question is accepted by the OP in comment, but not officially accepted?

For ex. [Protecting a cell, but allowing the drop down list to work](https://superuser.com/questions/925393/protecting-a-cell-but-allowing-the-drop-down-list-to-work/925396?noredirect=1#comment1251277_925396)

These are related, but not the same:
[Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/271976)
[Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/271976)

Comment: Related: [Community vote for “Accepted Answer” (Rep. >= 5000 only)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8600/271976) and [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3669/271976)

Comment: Related, but not the same!

Comment: Wait for it :-) Sometimes but not that often a user will mark accepted later, even way later. They are more likely to do so when they participate under the same user name for a longer period of time and understand the system, less likely to if you never see them again under that user name. That also means less likely to, if they do not like being here or how they get treated here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decision to "accept" an answer is up to the question asker. There is not, and never will be, any mechanism by which anybody other than the question asker can select the accepted answer. Voting already allows the community to indicate which answers they think are best.

If a user is new to the site and may not understand how it works, it's OK to politely let them know that they can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox, *if* they've already indicated in a comment that a particular answer solved their problem. You should never pressure a person into accepting an answer though.

Comment: Yep, and a lot of new users seem to ignore the little grayed-out checkmark. They think "it's grayed out, so I can't click it". Not sure if a new user commenting on an answer to their question displays that red dialog recommending them to accept the answer, either, but in many cases they'll just dismiss that without even reading it. Not much we can do about it really. But if an answer is particularly useful, the community's upvotes will *far* exceed the rep gain of the accept, making it pretty much a moot point.

Comment: Is there a notification reminding people to check their question?  This is my first question so I don't know.  Maybe I should just experiment.

Comment: @rfportilla - There is not.

Comment: @rfportilla I think there is actually, if the asker upvotes an answer, a box will say "you can also mark this as accepted"

Comment: Sure, I appreciate the info.  I didn't mean to make this a feature request, but if it doesn't annoy people too much, I think it would be a good idea to send people 1 or 2 notifications to remind them to give credit when it is due.  I don't get payment for this so the only satisfaction I get is knowing that someone was helped (and the few rep points that help to make this fun).